# Auto-exclude new changes in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

After a long break from TFS I'm forced to use it again (and seriously considering going the git-tfs route). Is there any setting in Visual Studio that would make all the changes I'm making, either directly or indirectly, start as 'Excluded' in Pending Changes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .tfignore files to set the files you want ingored? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful here - .tfignore allows me to ignore files. Instead, I want all the changes that are made to land in 'Excluded' set, where I would have to 'Include' them manually. Not quite unlike the concept of staging area in distributed VCSs.

Comment: When you try to add ignored files using the Add to Source Control dialog box (for example by dragging them into Source Control Explorer), they automatically appear in the Excluded items tab.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that - so that's a bit closer to what I want, but still not ok; that way, I'd more often than not forget to add those files when reviewing pending changes.